# Jasmine: How to test a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, karma-runner, jasmine-jquery

I'm very new to unit testing with Jasmine and I do have a question.
I have a simple button that add'toggle's a class on mousedown and mouseup:

```
$(function() {
    $('#OfficeUI a.button').on('mousedown mouseup', function(e) {
        $(this).addClass('ie-fix');
    });
});
```

My karma configuration file does contain the following:

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({
        basePath : '../../',
        files : [
            // Dependencies
            'Resources/External/Bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            'Resources/External/Bower/angular/angular.js',
            'Resources/External/Bower/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'Resources/Scripts/OfficeUI.js',
            'Resources/Scripts/Elements/OfficeUI.Elements.js',

            // Fixtures
            { pattern: 'Unit Tests/Fixtures/**/*.Test.html', watched: true,     served: true, included: false },

            // Files to test.
            { pattern: 'Unit Tests/**/*.Test.js', watched: true, server: true,     included: true }
        ],
        autoWatch : true,
        watched: true,
        server: true,
        include: false,
        frameworks: ['jasmine-jquery', 'jasmine'],
        browsers: ['Chrome']
    });
};
```

The plugin code is stored in the file: `OfficeUI.Elements.js` which is referenced from within the karma configuration file.

I do have fixture file containing the following logic:

```
<div id="OfficeUI">
    <a href="#" class="button">
        <span></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

So, according to my plugin, the anchor on this page should have a class `ie-fix` when a mousedown event is executed on it.

My test file itself is the following:

```
describe('Unit: OfficeUI Elements', function() {
    // Provides a section to define code to execute before every test is     executed.
    beforeEach(function() {
        jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/Unit Tests/Fixtures/';
    });

    it('A class \'ie-fix\' should be added to any \'a href\' which is marked     with a \'button\' class when you click the element.', function() {
        loadFixtures('OfficeUI.Elements.Test.html');
        $('#OfficeUI a.button').mousedown();
        expect($('#OfficeUI a.button')).toHaveClass('ie-fix');
    });
});
```

However, when I do execute the test, the following error pops up:

```
Expected ({ 0: HTMLNode, length: 1, prevObject: ({ 0: HTMLNode, context: HTMLNode, length: 1 }), context: HTMLNode, selector: '#OfficeUI a.button' }) to have class 'ie-fix'.
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

So, the test has failed, but I don't know why at all.
Anyone who has an idea?

**Edit: Changed to the current version**

I've modified everything and here's the new `karma.conf.js`

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({
        basePath : '../../',
        files : [
            // Resources
            'Resources/External/Bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            'Resources/External/Bower/angular/angular.js',
            'Resources/External/Bower/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'Resources/Scripts/OfficeUI.js',
            'Resources/Scripts/Elements/OfficeUI.Elements.js',

            // Fixtures
            { pattern: 'Tests/Fixtures/*.Test.html', watched: true, served:     true, included: false },

            // Unit Tests
            'Tests/**/*.Test.js'
        ],
        autoWatch : true,
        watched: true,
        server: true,
        include: false,
        frameworks: ['jasmine-jquery', 'jasmine'],
        browsers: ['Chrome']
    });
};
```

And the modified test runner file:

```
describe("Unit: OfficeUI Elements", function() {
    // Provides a section to define code to execute before every test is     executed.
    beforeEach(function() {
        jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/Tests/Fixtures/';
        loadFixtures('OfficeUI.Elements.Button.Test.html');
    });

    it("A class 'ie-fix' should be added to any 'a href' which is marked with a     'button' class when you click the element.", function() {

        $('#OfficeUI a.button').first().click();

        expect($('#OfficeUI a.button').first()).toHaveClass('ie-fix');
    });
});
```

The unit test does still fail.

Kind regards,

Comment: Maybe it's a silly comment, but where are you clicking on the element? Perhaps you should trigger either `mousedown` or `mouseup` on the element and then look for the class. I think.

Comment: Under the fixtures, I normally execute `$('#OfficeUI a.button').mousedown()` but even then, the test does fails. It seems that my jQuery plugin is not loaded onto my page, but I don't know on how I should do that.

Comment: Have you tried with `$(elem).trigger('mousedown')` instead?

Comment: I have updated my question with what I've tried so far and it's still failing. Any idea on how to solve?